# WSO2 API manager multi-tenant distributed setup

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2

I installed and configured a distributed setup of WSO2 API Managager with multitenancy enabled. I have 2 distributed gateways and i followed this guide https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Distributed+Deployment+of+the+Gateway . I created one tenant (we will call it tenantA) and deployed some APIs under it.

The problem is that with multitenancy the Synapse APIs artifacts (for APIs created in tenants [and not in the super-tenant]) on the gateway are stored in APIM-HOME/repository/tenants/tenantA/synapse-configs/default/api and not under APIM-HOME/repository/deployments/server/.

The question is: Should I share both paths (NFS/glusterFS) between the gateways? If not, which one should I share?
How about the registry? I shared both the config and governance registry partitions, is it supposed to be like this?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

In the multi-tenancy use case, those API artifacts are getting created at repository/tenants location. You can find those locations in https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Common+Runtime+and+Configuration+Artifacts

Yes, you have to share both paths as token, revoke, etc. APIs exist in super tenant location.

You have to share the userdb and registry db for the GWs in the multi-tenancy use case. https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Understanding+the+Distributed+Deployment+of+WSO2+API-M

Comment: thank you. This should be added as a Note on the distributed deployment of the gateway!!